# TFS 2017 - Move SQL2016 db to SQL2017 and run as SQL2016

Tags: team-foundation-server

I understand that TFS2017 is not compatible with SQL2017, per documentation.  However, is it possible to move a TFS SQL2016 db into SQL2017 and run it as SQL2016?

I'm trying this now and get the following error when verifying configuration.

Error:  TF255146: The SQL Server instance you specified (DB Server) is version 'SQL Server vNext', which is not supported by this version of Team Foundation Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not supported. The version of the server must match the compatibility list. But if you upgrade TFS to Azure DevOps Server 2019, it will run happily against a newer SQL Server.